# Why the styling is not working in my express app?

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

The stylings are not working in this route: 'http://localhost:5000/exams/add-new'

But it is working with the other routes such as:

- 'http://localhost:5000'
- 'http://localhost:5000/exams'
- 'http://localhost:5000/about'

I have my CSS file in the assets folder:
`assets/css/styles.css`

Here is the server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use('/css', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/css')))

app.use('/', require('./server/routes/router'))

app.listen(5000)
```

And the index.ejs file in the views folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Header-->
    <header>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <h1 class="logo">
            <a href="/">B<span>log</span></a>
          </h1>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/exams">Exams</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!--/Header-->
    <br />

    <!-- Main Section -->
    <main>
     <h1>Home Page</h1>
    </main>
    <!-- Main Section -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the exams page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Header-->
    <header>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <h1 class="logo">
            <a href="/">B<span>log</span></a>
          </h1>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/exams">Exams</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!--/Header-->
    <br />

    <!-- Main Section -->
    <main>
      <!-- Add New Question Button -->
      <div class="addNewQuestionsButton">
        <a href="/exams/add-new-questions">
          <span>Add new questions</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Add New Question Button -->
    </main>
    <!-- Main Section -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening and what is the solution?

Comment: in the browser's Networking tab do you see css files that do not load / 404 ?

Comment: @Ron yes, it says 404 errror

Comment: on which URL exactly does it say 404 ? and where are you in relevance to that URL.. which URL do you have opened to see the 404 of which CSS resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your output HTML, make sure the CSS is loaded from path:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />`

instead of

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />`

This will bring consistency despite the `route` of your current URL

Comment: But, it is still the same

Comment: by the way, it's ejs file and '/assets/css/styles.css' doesn't solve the problem

Comment: on which URL exactly does it say 404 ? and where are you in relevance to that URL.. which URL do you have opened to see the 404 of which CSS resource? Also do not just copy/paste, but try to adjust the path of your output .css files so that they start with `/`

Comment: when i open the /exams route, in the network initiator section of styles.css, it says that the file is being loaded from 'http://localhost:5000/css/styles.css'. But, when I go to the /exams/add-new route, it says 'http://localhost:5000/exams/css/styles.css'.

Comment: that is exactly what I am saying.. so when you go to `/exams/add-new`, you need to have the css path again as: `localhost:5000/css/styles.css`, which will work? Assuming this is the correct CSS path? So in your code OUTPUT where you see `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />` this must be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />`. Find where this gets generated within your code, change it, and I believe you will solve your issue.

Comment: thanks, man. It works now. But why does it work now? can you please explain?

Comment: if had another route like: 'http://localhost:5000/exams/add-new/question', would I need to make changes to the link path of CSS style again?

Comment: when you DO have the leading `/` the path in the URL is starting ALWAYS from the root of your domain = `localhost:5000/`, when you do NOT have the leading `/` then the path of what you are loading is RELATIVE to the "FOLDER" or path you are in...

Comment: Once you understand the relative vs absolute URL paths, you would know how they work, and yes you should make that edit too...

Comment: https://www.seoclarity.net/resources/knowledgebase/difference-relative-absolute-url-15325/ or https://www.seoquake.com/blog/relative-or-absolute-urls/ are good starting points

Comment: will check into it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

in Html Add exact path of css :

```
assets/css/styles.css
```

Comment: it does not solve the problem

Comment: there's another problem too. I have only one styles.css file in my project. But in the network section, when i try to go to the 'http://localhost:5000/exams/add-new', it shows two error of loading styles.css file. Why?